# I have installed PIL with Homebrew, but when I try to import it, it says no module exists

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, homebrew

I have installed PIL with homebrew. It then says that there was a symlink error, and that is can be easily fixed by doing it again, but with a sudo. I did so. Now, when I go into python, and import Image, it doesn't work! I've tried import PIL, import image, import pil, and none of them work. When I try to install it again, it says `Error: pil-1.1.7 already installed`. Please help!

Comment: If I can't import PIL, how can I import Image from PIL?

Comment: Verify that you're using the right python, i.e. one by brew and not the system python. Also see if `brew doctor` reveals anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would see this issue if you were using the python binary that was not installed by homebrew along with a package that you did install via homebrew. Could you verify that the python binary you are using is not the one that was included in OS X by default?

Comment: Ok, so I do brew doctor, and it says

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    2to3
    2to3-2.7
    easy_install
    easy_install-2.7
    idle
    idle2.7
    pydoc
    pydoc2.7
    python
    python-config
    python2.7
    python2.7-config
    pythonw
    pythonw2.7
    smtpd.py
    smtpd2.7.py

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH. 

How can I fix this?

Comment: In the Terminal type: export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH and then attempt to run the python interactive interpreter, followed by the import you are trying. If this works fine, you can make this permanent in multiple ways...